# on Azure in repo's script of CI/CD for the best practices which code to use?

Tags: azure-devops

on Azure in repo's script of CI/CD for the best practices which code to use: JSON or PowerShell or CLI ?

which code from above is the best and professional way to use ?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you should provide some more information about your use case. All 3 items mentioned work together. You will use each when necessary.

Comment: for example:  in repo I create the script to build VMs  or  AKS,  to be executed by running release pipe line

Comment: "Best" is relative to each person, each organization, and each situation. Stack Overflow is intended for **specific** questions about software development and associated tools; it is not a discussion forum where people will provide you opinions.

Comment: I am not asking about opinion, I am asking about the best practice

Answer (score 0):

As for the best practices of script of CI/CD, each of them has their own features and could be used in it.

For example, when you would like to create the script  to build VMs, you could select the JSON one because through the JSON script, you could see all information of the VMs more directly than other kinds of scripts. You could see the example through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-build-deploy-azure-pipelines?tabs=java-script .

As for building AKS, you could use  Power shell to create the script as it needs fewer related properties to be defined while comparing with other scripts. You could see some examples in the following document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough-powershell

To be concluded, each kind of way to create the script is available for CI/CD and you could select which  you are used to using or according to the advantages of each script.